# How do debug DNS name resolution? (nslookup works, but telnet doesn't)

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, ipv6

I'm trying to connect to a website:

```
http://superuser.com.sixxs.org
```

i can ping the address:

```
C:\Users\Ian>ping /6 superuser.com.sixxs.org

Pinging ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net [2001:838:2:1::30:67] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2001:838:2:1::30:67: time=257ms
Reply from 2001:838:2:1::30:67: time=176ms
Reply from 2001:838:2:1::30:67: time=161ms
Reply from 2001:838:2:1::30:67: time=164ms

Ping statistics for 2001:838:2:1::30:67:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 161ms, Maximum = 257ms, Average = 189ms
```

<strike>But neither **ping**:</strike>

```
C:\Users\Ian>ping supersuer.com.sixxs.org
Ping request could not find host supersuer.com.sixxs.org.
  Please check the name and try again.
```

But i cannot browse to it (in **Chrome** or **ie**):

[image]

nor can i **telnet** to it

```
C:\Users\Ian>telnet superuser.com.sixxs.org 80
Connecting To superuser.com.sixxs.org...Could not open connection to the host,
  on port 80: Connect failed
```

---

But `nslookup` resolves the name fine, with an authority record and everything!

*First we flush the dns, just in case someone wants to suggest it is due to dns caching:*

```
C:\Users\Ian>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

*And now back to the lookup:*

```
C:\Users\Ian>nslookup superuser.com.sixxs.org
Server:  solo.avatopia.com
Address:  10.0.0.98

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net
Addresses:  2001:838:2:1:2a0:24ff:feab:3b53
          2001:960:800::2
          2001:1af8:4050::2
          2620:0:6b0:a:250:56ff:fe99:78f7
          2001:838:2:1::30:67
Aliases:  superuser.com.sixxs.org
```

All those addresses work:

- I can `ping` them
- I can `telnet` to port 80 on them
- I can browse in **Chrome** (e.g. `http://[2001:838:2:1::30:67]`) to them

The name even resolves when [I manually call the Windows API function GetAddrInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767107/getaddrinfo-cannot-resolve-ipv6-google-com-but-nslookup-can).

Why how can I diagnose what `ping`, `telnet`, `Chrome` and `Internet Explorer` are doing wrong?

**Note**: Wireshark is of now help because the dns server (`solo.avatopia.com`) is on the other side of an encrypted vpn link; and WireShark refuses to decrypt encrypted vpn traffic.

Comment: Your ping example has a typo.

Comment: What happens if you try to ping, telnet, or browse to the canonical name ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Where's the `ping` typo? i don't see it...

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ohhhh, `ping` needs the `/6` parameter; it doesn't understand that if it only could resolve an ipv6 address it needs to send an IPv6 ICMP packet.

Comment: silly question, but is the web server itself set up to work on ipv6? does it work on ipv4 or other known ipv6 capable systems? Did you try connecting to the ipv6 equivilent of localhost?

Comment: It's a well-known ISP that provides IPv6 transition access. By appending `sixxs.org` or a domain name, they will let you access an IPv4 site through IPv6. This is useful for people who do not have IPv4 connectivity to the internet; only ipv6.

Comment: @IanBoyd: your original question had you pinging supersuer, not superuser.  That was the typo I was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS resolution does not automatically mean HTTP reachability; in your case, that is in fact part of the problem.

`sixxs.org` answers *all* DNS queries with a `CNAME` to `ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net`.  As an example, `iamugly` obviously couldn't be a real site, since there is no top-level domain.

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig +short iamugly.sixxs.org
ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net.
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig +short google.com.sixxs.org
ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net.
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig google.com.sixxs.org

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> google.com.sixxs.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22229
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.sixxs.org.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.sixxs.org.   3553    IN      CNAME   ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
sixxs.net.              3316    IN      SOA     ns.paphosting.net. hostmaster.sixxs.net. 2012010601 86400 7200 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon May 28 15:39:58 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 133

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

`ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net` is just an HTTP proxy that forwards traffic, so as long as their proxy is up, it is ping-able and you can `telnet` to it...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ telnet superuser.com.sixxs.org 80
Trying 2620:0:6b0:a:250:56ff:fe99:78f7...
Connected to ipv6.nginx.sixxs.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

After you go to `superuser.com.sixxs.org`, `sixxs.net` redirects you through `ipv6gate.sixxs.net` and they rewrite Super User's html content send all links on the page through `foo.sixxs.org`.

[image]

Something is preventing you from going through `sixxs.org`, and it probably comes from a vpn server, firewall or transparent http proxy elsewhere in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my **guess** about what is going.

(I was originally going to post this as a comment, but its too long, so I will post it as an answer and leave it up to yourself and/or others to decide if it is correct.)

I think this isp have their nameservers configured to reply to every subdomain.

I tried a random GUID and yes **0937c1fa-15dc-4a3a-837c-b9ada0953a7e.sixxs.org** resolves (and to the same ip addresses as superuser.com.sixxs.org)

This means all traffic to 0937c1fa-15dc-4a3a-837c-b9ada0953a7e.sixxs.org will be sent to them.  When it gets to them, they are probably examining the http host header to determine how to handle it. In the case of 0937c1fa-15dc-4a3a-837c-b9ada0953a7e.sixxs.org, I would suspect they would simply ignore the request as they are unlikely to know what to do with it.

In the case of superuser.com.sixxs.org, you would think that they should be redirecting this to superuser.com which but this does not appear to work.

I don't think it is possible for anyone outside their setup to know for sure why this does not work, but it  could be because they have some internal mapping wrong and it is sending to the wrong destination.

Another possibility is that they may not be providing this service to everyone and it is possible that if a non-subscriber attempts to use this address, it will simply ignore the request.

Bottom line is, I'm not really sure whether telnet, Chrome and Internet Explorer are actually doing anything wrong and I would suggest checking with sixxs.net before assuming there is anything wrong with your setup.

Answer (score -1):

I had a simliar issue, here's what I tried.

1. It could be related to Winsock's LSP, try [LSP fix](http://www.cexx.org/lspfix.htm) to find out error causing stuff.
2. [Reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)
3. Run `sfc /scannow` to fix any problems that might arise due to corrupted files.
4. Reset WinSock `netsh winsock reset` 
   5.Though totally unrelated try resetting your Branch Cache `netsh branchcache reset`
   6.Reset IPv6 configuration `netsh int ipv6 reset`
   7.Try Removing and reinstalling your network adapter from the Device Manager

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are only having trouble with the one site, or if it is all websites you cannot connect to (and are using a different pc to post this), but if you're getting DNS errors in your browsers for every site and you still have connectivity and you can ping stuff, give these few commands a try. It's not always one of these, but I have literally never seen all of them not work for your problem.

```
netsh winsock reset catalog

netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log

netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /renew

ipconfig /registerdns
```