# Can't browse websites using IPv6

Tags: windows-7, ipv6

I have configured my Windows 7 to use IPv6 (auto IP & OpenDNS IPv6 DNS) / IPv4 disable. Now the problem is that only `ipv6.google.com` is working but no other website is opening.

How do I access all websites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Enable IPv4.**

You cannot access *all* websites because even today, very few support IPv6. Even `superuser.com`, for example, can only be reached over IPv4.

Comment: its mean if i have ipv6 ..i can only access web that are ipv6 .. cant access website which are on ipv4 ? rite ?

Comment: @OneZero: **If you disable IPv4**, then you can only access websites that have IPv6.

Comment: thankyou for ur reply .. the thing is that i have ipv6 address only ...is there any potability that i can browse ipv4 websites

Comment: @OneZero there will be a long transition period where you need both IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity to access the "whole" Internet. IPv4 addresses will increasingly be behind multiple layers of NAT, but for the foreseeable future, you'll still need to have some form of IPv4 connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

[As I learned today](https://superuser.com/questions/429369/how-do-debug-dns-name-resolution-nslookup-works-but-telnet-doesnt), you can append `.sixxs.org` to a URL to use their IPv6 tunneling service.

For example `superuser.com.sixxs.org`

Comment: yes it is working